# Disable button if input value is whitespace? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

i want to disable button if the value in the input is whitespaces. Cant really find anything about in in React.

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={username === " "} /> //here's my button
```

Right now it only disable when i type in 1 whitespace but i always want it to disable whenever there is a whitespace. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if there is an whitespace.
  `<Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={username.includes(" ")} />`

Answer (score 2):

Can use `Regexp.Test` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

`/\s/.test(username)` would return true if username contains *any* whitespace and false if not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={username.includes(" ")} />
```

Or

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={(/\s/g).test(username)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Few ways to do it:

1. check index: `username.indexOf(' ') >= 0`
2. Check if it includes: `username.includes(' ')`
3. Use regEx: `/\s/g.test(username)`